# no applicable method for 'ggplot_build' applied to an object of class "logical"

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm using ggarrange two combine 8 geom_density_ridges plots. I would like a common legend, but when I use this command:

```
ridge <- ggarrange(pcp,rhum,smst,srad,psurf,runoff,tmed,wind,nrow=2,common.legend = TRUE)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in UseMethod("ggplot_build") : no applicable method for 'ggplot_build' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

I can't see what I've done differently from the example here:

https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggarrange.html

Hope someone can help.

thanks,

Josh

Comment: As the error message tries to tell you, one of the `pcp,rhum,smst,srad,psurf,runoff,tmed,wind` variables probably isn't a plot but a logical vector. Try plotting them individually and if one just prints a logical vector, that is likely where the error is coming from.

Comment: What happens if you try: `ridge <- ggarrange(pcp,rhum,smst,srad,psurf,runoff,tmed,wind,nrow=2,common.legend = FALSE)`

Comment: @Tarjae I get the same message. @teunbrand they all print fine separately. I think it is treating `common.legend = TRUE` as if it were a plot, for some reason, because when I run the command without that, it combines the plots fine, just each with their own legend.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so turns out there are multiple `ggarrange`s. I was trying to use the command with the `egg` package, but `common.legend` only works with the one in `ggpubr`. Problem solved. Thanks.